# Jquery validation not working second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

The problem is this jquery validation is not working in my form second time. Its working first time perfectly but second time its shows error message but form is going to submit. The code is here

```
 (function ($, W, D) {
        var JQUERY4U = {};

        JQUERY4U.UTIL =
        {
            setupFormValidation: function () {
                //form validation rules
                $("#aspnetForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        firstname: "required",
                        lastname: "required",
                        company: "required",
                        jobtitle: {
                            required: true,
                        },
                        phone: {
                            required: true,
                            number: true
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },

                    },
                    messages: {
                        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
                        lastname: "Please enter your last name",
                        company: "Please enter your company name",
                        jobtitle: "Please enter your job title",
                        phone: "Please enter a valid phone number",

                        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) {

                        $('#aspnetForm').on('submit', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            if (flag) {
                                createListItem();
                            }
                        });

                        //form.submit(function (e) {
                        //    e.preventDefault();
                        //    if (flag) {
                        //        createListItem();
                        //    }
                        //});


                    }
                });
            }
        }

        //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
        $(D).ready(function ($) {
            JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
            $('#newsletterModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
                clearFields();
            });
            $('#newsletterModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $('#lblMsg').empty();
            });
        });

    })(jQuery, window, document);
```

can any one help me

Comment: have you got any console errors

Comment: not getting any console error

Comment: For starters, stop following that horrifically verbose `JQUERY4U` tutorial.  Please explain the issue better.  Where is your relevant HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `submitHandler` callback function...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $('#aspnetForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (flag) {
            createListItem();
        }
    });
}
```

**Do not put a `submit` event handler inside of the `submitHandler` callback!**  It's unclear to me what you're trying to do but *[the `submitHandler`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler) callback function of the plugin has already captured & replaced the default submit event of the form*.

Also, whenever you declare your own `submitHandler` function, you are over-riding the default built into the plugin.  Since I see nothing inside of your custom `submitHandler` that submits the form, the form will never be submitted.

You'll either need to remove the `submitHandler` to allow the form to be submitted (when valid) as per the default functionality OR you'll need to put `$(form).submit()` inside of it someplace.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    if (flag) {
        createListItem();
    }
    $(form).submit();
}
```

---

**NOTE**:

Wrapping up everything like this is superfluous, unnecessary, verbose, and arcane...

```
(function($,W,D) {
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function() {
            $("#aspnetForm").validate({ .... });
        }
    }

    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

It serves no useful purpose other than to cause more confusion to those seeking guidance. *It comes from a popular, yet poorly explained, [online demo/tutorial by Sam Deering](http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/) that is linked to/from many places.*

The entire mess above can be removed and simply replaced by putting the `.validate()` method inside of the DOM ready event handler function...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#aspnetForm").validate({ .... });

});
```